# How to set Selenium browsers to treat Selenium's hub as a proxy server in python on Selenium Grid?

Tags: python, proxy, selenium, selenium-grid

I'm running Selenium 2.0b4dev on Selenium Grid in Ubuntu 10.04, using Python code to write test cases. I've been having trouble with getting basic HTTP authentication to a specific site working, and with a quick google search found that my problem could be solved with the addition of the line self.selenium.add_custom_request_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % _encoded) (with a proper line break in the middle to conform to PEP 8, of course.)

Unfortunately, apparently also through my search I found in order for that line of code to work I need to configure my browser (whichever one I'm using to run the test cases on the grid) to treat Selenium's (automatically running, apparently?) proxy server as a proxy for that browser to use. But apparently I need to modify the profile of Firefox (or IE)'s launcher to automatically use that proxy, since the whole point of these Selenium Grid test cases is that they aren't supposed to require user intervention, and I have little to no idea how to do that. I've just been using the "ant launch-hub" and "ant launch-remote-control" and then running python programs on the hub that import selenium and unittest.

If anyone could help, that would be just fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote up an article on how to do this in Ruby.  It links to a complementary article on testing self-signed certificates and gives you the set of flags you need to launch Selenium with.

http://mogotest.com/blog/2010/06/23/how-to-perform-basic-auth-in-selenium

To pass args through from grid to the underlying RC server, you need to use something like:

`ant -DseleniumArgs="-trustAllSSLCertificates" launch-remote-control`

Re: browsers . . . firefox will auto-enable the proxy mode stuff if you pass `trustAllSSLCertificates` now.  Otherwise you need to use *firefoxproxy.  IE requires the use of *iexploreproxy or a custom HTA launcher that configures the proxy (the article links to one we open-sourced but would need to be updated to work with 2.0 beta 4).

Comment: By "Firefox will auto-enable the proxy mode", do you mean I'll have to patch the Firefox launcher like you did in the "How to Accept Self-Signed SSL Certificates in Selenium" page and then pass that -DseleniumArgs? Or can I just pass that flag in and have it work without patching in the latest version of Selenium Grid? I tried passing that flag in my remote and it still didn't work, and I've spent the time since finding those two articles of yours fruitlessly looking for where and what I should be patching to make Firefox acknolwedge the proxy. (Perhaps I need to add -avoidproxy to the hub?)

Comment: Oh, and in addition to thanking you for the response, I should also ask if you're using Selenium 1.X or 2.X on your Grid. I read something saying that your clever solution didn't work anymore in 2.X, but for reasons that didn't make sense to me.

Comment: I need to add a note to that post.  Since it was written, I applied that patch to the *firefox launcher in trunk.  It was added in 2.0a5 or so.  IE still requires a custom launcher if you want to use it in HTA mode.

Comment: The post was written for the Selenium 1.x API, which is still present in the 2.x distribution.  Configuring proxies is completely different in the WebDriver API.  If you're using grid 1.x, you're using the Selenium 1.x API, so the article is still accurate.

Comment: I'm using Grid 1.0.8 and the -DseleniumArgs="-trustAllSSLCertificates" flag on my remote control, and still no luck. Thanks for the help, though. I also tried all four combinations of either passing "-avoidProxy" to the hub by adding it in -DseleniumArgs when I ran launch-hub (or not passing in "-avoidProxy"), and pointing the Selenium startup to the hub self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://localhost:4444") and then using open on the site I need to authenticate (or just opening it directly to target.) All four combinations need the user to type in the password.

Comment: You could just be setting the header incorrectly then.  I really didn't understand the note about the line break for PEP 8.  But if you're calling addCustomRequestHeader, there shouldn't be any line breaks.

Comment: That's just a "don't make any lines longer than 80 characters" thing. PEP 8 is the style guide for Python.

Comment: This is getting a bit verbose back-and-forth.  If you want, I'm in the #selenium channel on irc.freenode.net as "nirvdrum" most days.  I'd be happy to help you out and we can just recap the resolution here for posterity.